# Background thread with Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've done some research and have found some decent info on objective-C code, but almost nothing for Swift. I figure this is a pretty common pattern so hopefully we can hammer out how to do it correctly. I've made some pretty significant progress and feel like I'm pretty close, but I'm just out of my depth in Swift.

**Goal:** Make an app that uses a background thread to parse data and do long fetch requests, and have a main thread that uses an NSFetchedResults Controller.

Code from one of my functions to spin off a new Thread

```
let tQueue = NSOperationQueue()
let testThread1 = testThread()

tQueue.addOperation(testThread1)
testThread1.threadPriority = 0
testThread1.completionBlock = {() -> () in
    println("Thread Completed")
}
```

Class I made for making a thread

```
class testThread: NSOperation{
    var delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    var threadContext:NSManagedObjectContext?

    init(){
        super.init()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func main(){
        self.threadContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        threadContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator
        ...
        //Code that actually does a fetch, or JSON parsing
        ...
        threadContext!.save(nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func contextDidSave(notification: NSNotification){
        let sender = notification.object as NSManagedObjectContext
        if sender !== self.threadContext{
            self.threadContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

I won't include all the code for the NSFetchedResultsController, but I have one linked to the main context. When my threading is commented out the app runs fine, it will block the UI and parse/fetch the data that needs to be inserted into core data, and when it is all complete the UI will unlock.

When I add the threading, as soon as I do anything in the UI that could trigger a save to the main context (in this case, the tappedOnSection table function performs a save), the app crashes and the only thing that appears in the console is. "lldb". The line that is highlighted that triggered the error was

```
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
```

The error next to it is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, address=...

If I simply wait for the background thread to complete, upon completion, I get an error also this time tracing to the "didChangeObject" method of the NSFetchedResultsController. It says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value, and flags the following case:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch(type){
        ... other cases
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            self.configureCell(self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
       ...other cases
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming I'm having some problem with concurrency that I'm not handling properly. I thought that the NSNotification that watched for changes handles this, but I must be missing something else.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)

    ...
    //Code here calls the function that starts the thread shown previously to do a background fetch

}

func contextDidSave(notification: NSNotification){
    let sender = notification.object as NSManagedObjectContext
    if sender !== self.managedObjectContext!{
        println("Save Detected Outside Thread Main")
        self.managedObjectContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

With some help from you guys I've been able to localize the error. It seems that the didChangeObject method from the NSFetchedResultsController is the problem. If the data changes, or new rows are inserted, the didChange Object method fires off respective methods to perform these animations, its here where I get the nil errors. Obviouslly, the whole point is that when the background data is fetched, that it will just smoothly animate in, but instead of doing this, it blows up. If I comment this function out, than I don't get any errors, but also loose the smooth animation I hope for. The attached didChangeObject method is below. It is mostly straight from the swift documentation on NSFetchedResultController:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch(type){
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            if self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) != nil{
                self.configureCell(self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            }

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check whether `self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` is nil before calling `self.configureCell...` - it can be nil if the relevant row is no longer visible.

Comment: This seemed to help fix some of the errors that I was getting, I still got a concurrency error from when a save was occurring on the main and the background context at the same time, but it didn't crash the app, it just messed up the UI for around 15 seconds, and then it magically fixed itself. Do I need to be performing a tableView.reloadData in my contextDidSave method?

Comment: The FRC delegate methods ought to pick up the requisite changes to the tableView, but given you may have many updates coming in from the background, you could just put a reloadData in the `controllerDidChangeContent:` method.

Comment: Its working! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Not related to your crash, but... "but I must be missing something else." Yes. You are using queue confinement. Do not use merge notifications with queue confinement to communicate changes between contexts, use context nesting instead. Merge notifications are appropriate for thread confinement, but for many reasons do not work correctly with queue confinement. Also see: http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93190211147/secrets-of-nsfetchedresultscontroller-happiness and http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/97430076027/a-real-guide-to-core-data-concurrency

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why this isn't stated more clearly in Apples docs on concurrency. I understand to a degree what you stated in your post. My main issue is now understanding how to do this same thing in Swift.

Comment: I think you still have some indexPath problems in `didChangeObject`: in the `.Update` case, you test `cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) != nil`, but pass `cellForRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath!)` to `configureCell`.  You should use `indexPath!`.  Likewise in the .Move case, you use `indexPath!` for both the delete and insert: you should delete from `indexPath!` and insert at `newIndexPath!`.  Also, in your `numberOfRowsInSection`, you need to access the particular element in the sections! array for the current section: exactly as you do for `viewForHeaderInSection` at lines 226 and 227.

Comment: Uh, why do you want the NSFetchedResultsController to use the main thread? This would seem to be very much counter to your other stated goals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I ended up researching the many different ways to do threading. The most useful turned out to be the Multiple contexes, with the Notification center as described [here](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout) I also implemented the multiple contexts solution, but degraded back to the other in the end. My issue turned out to be that I was sharing a delegate between multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers without checking if the incoming controller was the same as the one that the table was currently using. This produced out of bounds errors whenever the data auto-reloaded.

My background thread solution was simple.

1. Create a main Context
2. Create a background Context.
3. Call the background context using the performBlock

   ```
   context.performBlock {
      //background code here
   ```
4. Listen for changes with the main context.

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)

   func contextDidSave(notification: NSNotification) {
       let sender = notification.object as NSManagedObjectContext
       if sender != managedObjectContext {
           managedObjectContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
       }
   }
   ```
5. Merge the changes into the mainContext.

My initial setup was actually quite close to correct, what I didn't know was that when you setup your backgroundContext you can give it a concurrency type

```
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

then you can call the context in a background thread using context.performBlock (as shown above) whenever you want to do background thread stuff.

Also, the NSFetchedResultsController used the mainContext as their context so that they wouldn't get blocked during parsing.

**UPDATE**

There are multiple ways to do background threads, the above solution is just one. Quellish describes another popular approach [in his article here](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93190211147/secrets-of-nsfetchedresultscontroller-happiness). It is very informative and I recommend it, it describes the nested context approach to the queue confinement.

Comment: Your solution uses queue confinement, but does not uses nested contexts to communicate changes? Your NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is going to arrive on the background context's queue. Your merge will be happening on the wrong queue. For this (and many other!) reasons, when using queue confinement it's best to use nested contexts to communicate changes.

Comment: @quellish, I ended up implementing both the nested contexts version as you described and the notification merge version. Due to performance buffs described in this article http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout my team is leaning on using the notification version. Both are working without any bugs however. The main reason for the bugs I was getting was the 3 fetched results controllers that we switch between sharing a single delegate.I edited my solution to reference nested contexts to help those with similar problems in the right direction.

Comment: If you use notifications with nested contexts, you *will* have difficult to troubleshoot bugs. You are using two conflicting methods of communicating changes between contexts. Were you actually able to measure a performance issue using Instruments?

Comment: I did not perform any myself, just what I read from that article. I'm very curious though if his statements are true, if they aren't than I would definitely lean the other way. Like I said though, I've got a working branch with that method as well, so if we bump into issues with it, I'll swap back to nested contexts, its a pretty simple fix. I'll post if I get any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether `self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` is nil before calling `self.configureCell...` - it can be nil if the relevant row is no longer visible.

The FRC delegate methods ought to pick up the requisite changes to the tableView, but given you may have many updates coming in from the background, you could just put a `reloadData` in the `controllerDidChangeContent:` method.

Comment: Thanks again, I could of sworn it was a problem with my Threading, but it ended up being more FetchedResultController issues. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it broke again. Now on the insertRow from the same method. What I did to produce this was delete the app off the simulator so that it would have to reload everything into core data, I'm assuming the whole purpose of the didChangeObject method, is to provide smooth animations when you edit or insert rows. Well, whenever I edit or insert a row it throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You should insert at `newIndexPath`, and delete from `indexPath`. And likewise for moves.

Comment: I swapped indexPath with newIndexPath and the updated rows don't appear unless I reload the app a second time.

Comment: Nothing works with the didChangeObject method, I think quellish is on the right track though. I need to be using context nesting to solve this problem, the notification thing does not work well.

Comment: "You should insert at newIndexPath, and delete from indexPath. And likewise for moves" That will actually stimulate bugs. http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/

Comment: @quellish - thanks for pointing out that bug.  It seems to relate to the use of `configureCell` rather than the text you quoted.  Or am I missing something deeper?

Comment: Yes. An insert should be an insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, a move should be a 
moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:, an update should be a 
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, etc. Use the appropriate table view methods, do not try to outsmart it. The examples provided by some of the Core Data templates have bugs. Very bad bugs. Breaking the internal state of the table by returning 0 for the number of sections, etc.